# Display Razor markup as text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to show a piece of Razor markup as a text example on a page. I need to show following code (for example)

```
 <div class="editor-wrap">
    <div class="editor-label">
    <text>
        @Html.LabelFor( model => model.StartDate, new { data_tooltip_message = "Some text" } )
        </text>
    </div>
</div>
```

so I have regular Html plus Razor markup, I know that to show Html you have to wrap it with

```
<XMP>
```

tag, but Razor is parsing its markup anyway and is throwing exception where I want it only to display plain text. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>`<XMP>` is not recommended actually. Something like `<code>` or `<pre>` is preferred. Alternatively you can HTML encode the text so that it's rendered the way you expect on the page.</strike>.

**Update**: Sorry, I see what your trying to do now. The  tag only tells the browser to stop parsing HTML, but razor still tries to parse it's code because of the @ character. To get around this escape the character by putting a second @ in there.

```
<xmp>
    <div class="editor-wrap">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <text>
                @@Html.LabelFor( model => model.StartDate, new { data_tooltip_message = "Some text" } )
            </text>
        </div>
    </div>
</xmp>
```